# running grails application on eclipse-possible plugin error

Tags: eclipse, grails, plugins

I am working to set up grails on a local system and am working through the tutorials at:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXHxo43hn34&feature=relmfu

However, all the controller and domain class files compile correctly, but I receive the errors listed below whenever I try to execute the app

I had difficulties installing the plugins because the componenets could not be accessed, and installed all necessary plugins that I could reach, but am unsure if these are the source of the problem.

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2012-05-24 10:24:21,801 [pool-7-thread-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  -     Error executing bootstraps: Error creating bean with name   'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
Line | Method
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
->>  334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    166 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.example.pomodoro.Task.details() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[blank:false]]
Possible solutions: getAll(), getDetials(), getTags(), getId(), equals(java.lang.Object), setDetials(java.lang.String)
->>   16 | doCall    in org.example.pomodoro.Task$__clinit__closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    334 | innerRun  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|    166 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The original error is a `MissingMethodException` in `org.example.pomodoro.Task` for the `details` field.  I'm assuming it has to do with setting constraints as it's complaining about setting `[blank:false]`.  This root error can be seen at the end of the first long Error line in your trace.

Because suggested solutions on the next line are `getDetials()` and `setDetials()`, do you have a typo in your domain class for the property `details` -> `detials`?

Comment: Thanks that seemed to do the trick.  I guess eclipse doesn't point to the errors in grails like it does an regular java, and I need to get familiar with the error messages